# Getting first href you find above element in DOM

Tags: html, dom, web-scraping, screen-scraping, domdocument

I'm scraping HTML text and its `href` element, for example:

```
<a href="Scrape this">Also scrape this</a>
```

However, in some cases there's no `href` in the enclosing text container. Instead, it might be one level up:

```
<a href="Scrape this"><div>Also scrape this</div></a>
```

Here's the code I'm currently using for the scraping:

```
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$row = $xpath->query($job_location);

foreach ($row as $job) {    
    $jobs = array();
    $jobs['title'] = $job->nodeValue;
    $jobs['link'] = $root.$job->getAttribute('href');
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `getAttribute('href')` which returns the `href` for the element I have selected.

My question is: is there an alternative that will instead get the first `href` it finds, either directly encasing the element or further up the tree so that it would work for either of the two HTML examples above?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
$xpath->query('./preceding::*[@href][1]', $job)->item(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem is that I'm having trouble making multiple Xpath queries - is there an alternative that can be a direct replacement for `getAttribute`?

Comment: Do you mean an alternate to using xpath?